# How to show that this set is bounded?

Tags: calculus

> Given set $\{3 - x \mid x < 0\}$, find if it is bounded.

So, from intuition it should be bounded from below, but how to show it?

Comment: It's bounded from below: $x<0 \, \implies 3-x>3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x<0$ then $3-x>3$, so the set in question is the open interval $(3,\infty)$. Hence it is bounded below (by $3$ for instance) but not above.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Equation of straight line for real x]

Proof without words in this plot.